# playframework JPA.em().merge(this)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, h2, playframework-2.2

I am trying to Insert my form  to h2 database.
I am using hibernate and jpa. Here is the code

```
package models;
import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import play.data.format.*;
import play.data.validation.*;
import play.db.jpa.*;

@Entity
public class MedicalIncident   {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String month;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String place;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String unit;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String incident_type;

    @Constraints.Required
    public int age;


    /**
     * Insert this new incident submission.
     */
    @Transactional
    public void toDataBase() {
        // persist object - add to entity manager
        JPA.em().merge(this);
        JPA.em().persist(this);
    }


}
```

I am faceing an issue. Here is an error:

```
 [PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement]
```

Its look like it using ebean instead of jpa/hibernate. I am guesting from stack trace:

```
[info] play - datasource [jdbc:h2:mem:SupraCIRS] bound to JNDI as DefaultDS
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:h2:mem:SupraCIRS
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
[error] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - Kolumna "MEDICALINC0_._EBEAN_INTERCEPT" nie istnieje
Column "MEDICALINC0_._EBEAN_INTERCEPT" not found; SQL statement:
select medicalinc0_.id as id1_0_0_, medicalinc0_._ebean_intercept as _ebean_i2_0_0_, medicalinc0_.age as age3_0_0_, medicalinc0_.incident_type as incident4_0_0_, medicalinc0_.month as month5_0_0_, medicalinc0_.place as place6_0_0_, medicalinc0_.unit as unit7_0_0_ from MedicalIncident medicalinc0_ where medicalinc0_.id=? [42122-172]
[error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
[error] application - 

! @6ghh1j2nn - Internal server error, for (POST) [/incydent_medyczny/zapisz] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1316) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:898) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at models.MedicalIncident.toDataBase(MedicalIncident.java:40) ~[na:na]
        at controllers.MedicalIncidents.submit(MedicalIncidents.java:50) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:159) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1859) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.6.Final.jar:4.2.6.Final]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Kolumna "MEDICALINC0_._EBEAN_INTERCEPT" nie istnieje
Column "MEDICALINC0_._EBEAN_INTERCEPT" not found; SQL statement:
select medicalinc0_.id as id1_0_0_, medicalinc0_._ebean_intercept as _ebean_i2_0_0_, medicalinc0_.age as age3_0_0_, medicalinc0_.incident_type as incident4_0_0_, medicalinc0_.month as month5_0_0_, medicalinc0_.place as place6_0_0_, medicalinc0_.unit as unit7_0_0_ from MedicalIncident medicalinc0_ where medicalinc0_.id=? [42122-172]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329) ~[h2.jar:1.3.172]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169) ~[h2.jar:1.3.172]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146) ~[h2.jar:1.3.172]
        at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.optimize(ExpressionColumn.java:144) ~[h2.jar:1.3.172]
        at org.h2.expression.Alias.optimize(Alias.java:52) ~[h2.jar:1.3.172]
        at org.h2.command.dml.Select.prepare(Select.java:808) ~[h2.jar:1.3.172]
```

I dont understand: I've precise jpa in conf:

```
application.name="SupraCIRS"
application.lang.cookie=SUPRACIRS_LANG
application.secret="r5Wd;ABfd7;e^F3p9WUl2132Y13v213g12K3ljoIdsg`MU8`YL:x`8KAhgao21ofwb?iQJe6hL0I6liIg121211"
application.langs="pl"

db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:SupraCIRS"
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS

jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit

ebeanEnabled=false
logger.root=ERROR
logger.play=INFO
logger.application=DEBUG
http.port=8081
```

file build.sbt

```
import play.Project._

name := """SupraCIRS"""

version := "1.0-Alfa"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.2.0", 
    "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "2.3.1")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(javaJdbc, javaEbean)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.2.6.Final",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
  jdbc,
  javaCore,
  javaJdbc,
  javaJpa
)

playJavaSettings
```

conf/META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Plese help

Comment: Have you tried to add support for hibernate like it is described here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaJPA ?

Comment: Yes, I followed documentation

Comment: But I don't see those instructions in your conf file that you posted above..

Comment: What do You mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here: `libraryDependencies ++= Seq(javaJdbc, javaEbean)`. Remove the `javaEbean` part! This should also solve all your other problems.

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

I've dowload clean play zip. 
And create project over new. 
Then I put dir app configuration public from my old project into newly created.

Comment: I've really mess up my dependencies in project. I dont know why cleaning build.sbt wasnt enaught. I've had the same problem all the time. So I've made new project without ebean in build.sbt. I've got also new play (with clean local repository). All of this helped me. If You have better solution, share it with me!